# Can't query one record in BigQuery table, but can query others

Tags: google-bigquery, google-workspace

I export Google Workspace logs to BigQuery. There are a small number of top-level records and then many nested groups of records. I can query the top level of records and most sub-levels fine but I can't select the `groups` records. `select group_id,admin.user_email,admin.group_email` works fine, for example.

But when I try to run a very similar query on the Groups records it fails with `Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword GROUPS`

```
SELECT
  group_id,
  groups.group_email
FROM
  `workspace-analytics.workspace_prod.activity`
WHERE
  groups.group_email='group@domain.com'
LIMIT
  100;
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does this record in particular refuse to work the way the others do?

[image]

Comment: The error message tells you that `GROUPS` is a keyword. If you quote it, then bigquery will realise its a reference and not a keyword.  `\`groups\`.group_email`

Comment: So that worked, thank you — but why do I only need to do this for `groups` and not `admin`? EDIT: I spoke too soon, the results are funky — I just see the strings in the results, not the actual results

Comment: Because `admin` isn't a keyword. Imagine you had a column named `from`, you couldn't do `SELECT from FROM table` without confusing the shit out of the parser, but `SELECT \`from\` FROM table` isn't ambiguous at all. You can CHOOSE to quote all references regardless, but if they're keywords then they MUST be quoted.

Comment: Make sure you're quoting using backticks, the same ones you use in dataset names.

Comment: Oh my god, well that's obvious in retrospect (thank you). I've only used sequel in BQ and while I've used it before I must have never queried the groups and just didn't noticer. 
With backticks though, I'm seeing "unrecognized name".

Comment: @MatBailie, can you post the answer to the Answer section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from @MatBailie, posting it as a WikiAnswer:

The error message tells you that `GROUPS` is a keyword. If you quote it, then bigquery will realise its a reference and not a keyword. `groups`.group_email.

Because `admin` isn't a keyword. Imagine you had a column named from, you couldn't do SELECT from FROM table without confusing the shit out of the parser, but SELECT `from` FROM table isn't ambiguous at all. You can CHOOSE to quote all references regardless, but if they're keywords then they MUST be quoted.

Make sure you're quoting using backticks, the same ones you use in dataset names.